# How to make HTTP request on dart and pass parameters

Tags: dart, httprequest, url-parameters

A dart code for http requests and add parameters to the request.

Something like this, but in dart

```
params = {'key': '54321'}
resp = requests.get('https://api.example.com/test', data = params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these should do what you want:

```
resp = requests.get(Uri.https('api.example.com', 'test', params).toString());
```

or

```
resp = requests.get(Uri.parse('https://api.example.com/test').replace(queryParameters: params).toString());
```